# how can I stop chrome going to the bing.com search engine when chrome starts up?

Tags: google-chrome, bing

how can I stop chrome going to the bing.com search engine when chrome starts up?

Let's say I start Chrome, by clicking the chrome icon in the start menu, or going to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

So then it says "Who's using Chrome", and some of the profiles come up

I choose one of them, call it profile "A".

It then opens to

`https://www.bing.com/?pc=COS2&ptag=D080221-N0330A9FCDBB49EF&form=CONBDF&conlogo=CT3335799

[image]

If I highlight what's in the address bar, and type "abc" , it says a "G"

[image]

And if I hit ENTER, it uses Google to do that search

[image]

So the issue is only with what page Chrome opens up when I start it up. Not an issue with what search engine it uses when I enter a search term in the address bar.

If I an on some website and I click the "Home" buttom, then it goes to Chrome.

This link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-remove-bing-from-chrome  mentions about chrome extensions. So, incase it's related to some chrome extension.  If I go to another profile , one with very few chrome extensions,  It goes to `https://www4.bing.com/?form=DCDN`  That profile only has two chrome extensions listed.

Both of which are off

[image]

So I have no idea.

It seems to be pervasive across chrome profiles. Not related to any chrome extension.

Not to do with the homepage, and not to do with what search engine is used when entering terms in the address bar.

Comment: Open Chrome Settings -> On Startup, check if "Open a specific page or set of pages" is enabled and bing is listed. If yes, removed it. Restart chrome and verify if the issue is solved.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks that works, you can post that as an answer and i'll accept it. I see chrome has added an "on startup" section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Chrome Settings -> On Startup.
2. Check if "Open a specific page or set of pages" is enabled and bing.com is listed. If yes, removed it.
3. Restart chrome and verify if the issue is solved.